# Poor Bluetooth audio quality and delays on Dell Latitude with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio, bluetooth, dell-latitude, broadcom

I have been trying to use an LG Tone ([HBS700](http://www.lg.com/us/mobile-phones/mobile-accessories/LG-HBS700.jsp)) Bluetooth headset on Windows 7 with mixed results.

The PC is a Dell Latitude E6320, and the Bluetooth adapter is the Dell Wireless 375 Bluetooth module manufactured by Broadcom.

I am able to pair the headset with Windows and everything usually starts out fine.  However, after some time (maybe 15 minutes to 2 hours) problems start to arise.  The headset will disconnect & reconnect from the PC, and then audio quality turns in to something from a static filled radio.  Sometimes the audio quality will be ok, but the audio is delayed by a few seconds.

I can fix the issue by powering the headset on and off; or sometimes, I need to remove the pairing in Windows for it to work properly.  Other times, I need to power off the BT radio or reboot the laptop completely.

The headset works fine with any phones I've tried, so I'm confident the problem is with Windows or the laptop hardware.

Answer (score 4):

Bluetooth audio headsets are a complete nightmare, and worst when we talk about A2DP. If you want to use your Bluetooth headphones and guarantee music continuity, I recommend you get [Bluesoleil](http://www.bluesoleil.com/) which is a software that overrides the OS Bluetooth driver. You might get a much better performance than the one you're experiencing but still you'll keep getting the audio delay since, unfortunately, that's the way A2DP technology was conceived.

Comment: I ran into choppy Bluetooth audio as well, using an adapter (not the one listed above) seems to improve things greatly, almost no skipping.

Answer (score 2):

The same type of issue for me was resolved by buying a USB external dongle and installing the software. I am using now a [Rocketfish one](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/Rocketfish%22+-+Micro+Bluetooth+USB+Adapter/8820886.p?id=1207351932175&skuId=8820886) that works perfectly.

Bluetooth is not as good as it promises as I even have issues with delays on my phone and computer from time to time but getting better hardware helps.

Comment: This answer combined with @[George](http://superuser.com/posts/376945)'s above is probably your best solution - try Bluesoleil and then replace your USB Bluetooth dongle!

Answer (score 1):

First things first.  Just because it says "Bluetooth" does not mean that it is capable of doing anything/all things other Bluetooth devices are designed to do.  PC-based bluetooth chips are typically only capable of basic bluetooth functionality at best... (PIM exchange... PAN... OBEX... ) but when it comes to realtime data (Handsfree/A2DP) they frequently choke unless specifically designed to do such.  The Windows native bluetooth stack is also pretty horrible... and much of it requires the manufacturers' driver to do all the work.  Your best bet is to hope the latest drivers fix some of those issues.

http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/DriverDetails/DriverFileFormats?DriverId=R285455

That would be a great place to start.

Comment: I have tried that driver and a newer one from Dell without any improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Some observations most of my hardware dual boots Linux/Windows, Bluetooth works way better in Linux, the problem seems to lie with the Windows stack.

I have tried BlueSoliel and it works fine, but it seems ridiculous to pay >$20 for software to make a $4 dollar dongle work.

My $4 dongle does A2DP fine using either Linux or BlueSoliel