# Bluetooth headphones: great call quality on android, poor quality on PC

Tags: audio, bluetooth

I saw similar questions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/578021/bluetooth-headphones-great-quality-on-iphone-poor-quality-on-notebook-and-pc) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/724018/bad-sound-through-bluetooth-headphones), but I'm not really satisfied with that ones. So here it goes:

I've got Sony's SBH52 Bluetooth headset, and it works with great quality on calls connected to my ZenFone 5, and yes, I'm sure it is using two-way audio transfer somehow (for that, I mean it is not using the build in microphone of my phone, and just using the Bluetooth headset for output). It works perfectly fine during calls my old sony WT19i as well.

When I use it on my computer, it works great when using A2DP protocol, as expected, then, when I try to use the microfone on any application, such as Skype and TeamSpeak, it changes to Handsfree and the audio quality becomes terribly bad.

So I'm wondering, why does it happen? It makes no sense for me, how my phones can use two-way quality Bluetooth audio transfer while my computer cannot? Is there any other profile that my phone might support and my PC doesn't?

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I'm reading everything I can about this but can't seem to find an answer.

Comment: Sorry @sander but I was not. And this problem didn't persist in bothering me since I've never tried to use it anymore, so I didn't dig deeper into it.

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely your Bluetooth chip in your computer is unable to provide the best quality for both microphone and audio at the same time. Purchasing a Bluetooth dongle might help your problem.